# Which is the best way of multiple inheritance in php?

Tags: php, class, oop, traits, multiple-inheritance

I have main class, that should be extended by 3 specific class.

Main requirement is:

> -For OOP I need to demonstrate code structuring in meaningful classes that extend each other, so would be an abstract class for the main
>   product logic. An approach for this would be to have a product base
>   class, that would hold all logic common to all products and then
>   specific product type would extend the product base class with that
>   type-specific stuff.
>
> -The idea is to create an abstract class with all product common logic, like getTitle, setTitle etc. Then create child product classes
>   for each product type to store product type specific logic like
>   furniture sizes, CD size, book weight etc..

This task I have solved with **php traits**:

**Main.php**

```
class Main 
{
    use Book;
    use Disc;
    use Furniture;
    // common properties and methods
}
```

**Disc.php**

```
trait Disc
{
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }  
}
```

**Book.php**

```
trait Book
{
    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }
}
```

**Furniture.php**

```
trait Furniture
{
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }
    public function setLength($length)
    {
        $this->length = $length;
    }
}
```

---

I have solved this with interfaces like that:

**Main.php**

```
class Main
{
   // common properties
}
```

**Types.php**

```
interface Weight
{
    public function setWeight($weight);
}
interface Size
{
    public function setSize($size);
}
interface Fdim extends Weight,Size
{
    public function setHeight($height);
    public function setWidth($width);
    public function setLength($length);
}
class Furniture extends Main implements fdim
{
    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    } 
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }
    public function setLength($length)
    {
        $this->length = $length;
    }
}
```

**Is this the best solution with interfaces which responds to the above requirements?**

**Which is more acceptable traits or interfaces? What do you recommend?**

I have a question: Is there a better solution to this task with requirement above? I have tried abstract classes and interfaces as well, but in my opinion the requirements are more satisfied with traits. What do you recommend?

Comment: interfaces and traits woudl be the way to go. PHP like Java allows only single inherittance unlike C++ which allows multiple inherittance but has problems. Interfaces (and traits) can help in allowing sth similar to multiple inherittance

Comment: In my opinion it would be better to name interfaces like `HavingWeight`, and traits also more generic, like `WithWeight`, `WithSize` so you that there will be less need of using aliases in `use` statemenets. Then use abstract base class of `Furniture`, from which Chair, Table etc. will extend. You are naming traits like concrete classes here, for instance, that is the `Disc` should extend from abstract `DataCarrier` and the `DataCarrier` should use `WithSize` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I have written in comment, I would suggest something like this:

```php
abstract class Product
{
    // Get/Set title, SKU, properties which are common for *all* products
}
```

Then some interfaces:

```php
interface HavingWeight
{
    // Get/Set weight
}
```

Traits:

```php
trait WithWeigth
{
    // Get/Set weight implementation
}
```

Then concrete class of `Book`:

```php
class Book extends Product implements HavingWeight
{
   use WithWeight;
}
```

Using interfaces have the very important advantage, that use can then use code like following:

```php
if($product instanceof HavingWeight)
{
    // Show weight
}
```

Comment: #PeterM Please, Could you help me with section? what should put I inside body? 

`if($product instanceof HavingWeight)
{
    // Show weight
}`

Comment: Whatever is suitable for situation, this is example of using instance of product, you could `echo $product->getWeight()` and be certain that method `getWeight` in fact exists in current instance if `$product`

Comment: #PeterM I did this with this way, but there is errors.. Please see my answer down..

Answer (score 3):

As [Nikos M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591273/nikos-m) mentioned, *PHP* does not support *multiple inheritance* (at least not till now), and like you may have noticed, **traits** and **interfaces** would be the only way to simulate multiple-inheritance.

- Use **traits** if the same logic is required to be used by multiple classes (that do not extend or inherit each other).
- You could use **interfaces** too, but that would mean that you can not share the same function logic between different classes (which would force you to make some copy-paste or to think of some other workaround).